# How to get indexedDB storage quota in Safari 12.0.1?

Tags: safari, storage, indexeddb, navigator, quota

I would like to get a indexedDB storage quota estimate in Safari 12.0.01 but navigator.storage or navigator.storageQuota is undefined

`window.navigator.storage
navigator.storage.estimate()`